# Member-Value mechanics in label like comboboxes

Tags: wpf

Is there a way to use bindings at labels like bindings at comboboxes?
E.g.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="MyComboBox" 
                  DisplayMemberPath="SomeName" 
                  SelectedValuePath="SomeID" 
                  SelectedValue="{Binding SomeOtherProp.OtherID,Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Can I use a label like this? I want to set the content of the label depending on *SomeID*.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Clemens. I didn't know that converters can be applied to labels. That did the trick:

```
<Label Content="{Binding SomeID, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}" />
```

*MyConverter* does a simple lookup and returns the result.

Comment: Bind Content to SomeID and use a Binding Converter?